# How do you make a condition on a column in one table apply to every instance of a primary key?

Tags: join, conditional-statements

I have a table called 'Artists' which has columns Artist_ID, Artist_Name, Artist_Genre and a table called 'Albums' with Artist_ID, Album_Id, Album_Name, ALbum_Number_Songs etc.

I join these two tables via Artist_Id. Now I want to know all Artists who have never had an album with over 12 songs. 
I have tried this:

```
SELECT Distinct Artist_Name
FROM Artists
INNER JOIN Albums
ON Albums.Artist_ID=Artists.Artist_Id
WHERE Album_Number_Songs < 12
```

however this just checks all instances and output will be just on whether or not the album has < 12 not the artist overall...does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT Artist_Name FROM Artists 
WHERE Artists.Artist_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT Albums.Artist_ID FROM Albums WHERE Albums.Artist_ID = Artists.Artist_ID AND Albums.ALbum_Number_Songs > 12)
```

This also includes the artists with no albums which I think corresponds better to the initial task.

Comment: Please remember to mark whichever answer helped you resolve your issue as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select r.artist_name 
from artists r
left join albums l on r.artist_id = l.artist_id
group by r.artist_name
having max(l.album_number_songs) <= 12
```

Note: I have tested this on MS SQL Server, but I think this syntax should work for Oracle and MySQL too.